# how to set order in placeholder.control in recursive c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, recursion

results of the method "LevelControl" :

### |DIRUT KEU A| - |DIRUT KEU| - |DIRUT|

I want results like this

### |DIRUT| - |DIRUT KEU| - |DIRUT KEU A|

so, I have to add a row where the "sort"?

my code is :

```
    private void LevelControl(string parID)
    {
        DataSet ds = RunQuery("Select ID, Name, ManagerID from Users where ID = '" + parID + "'");
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
            btn.ID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + parID;
            btn.CommandArgument = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            btn.CommandName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            btn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(btn_command);                  
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);       

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2] != null)
            {
                parID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
                LevelControl(parID);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @knobs_downvoting_questions <-- stop down voting questions without some kind of explanation. Not being able to take two minutes to try and understand what someone is asking is not a valid reason to down vote a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your button to the placeholder after your recursion.

```
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2] != null)
    {
        parID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
        LevelControl(parID);
    }
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Comment: I would probably move all of the button creation code below the conditional that recursively calls LevelControl.